# mqtt message not sent in qos 2 of pub and sub clients

Tags: python, mqtt

Environment

- OS: CENTOS 6.5
- EMQ: 2.3.1

PUB client is qos 2 and SUB client is qos 2. But do not subscribe.

SUB Client

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.connect("localhost", port=1993, keepalive=60)
mqttc.subscribe("TEST", 2)
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

PUB Client

```
for i in xrange(0, 100):
    print 'i:{}'.format(i)
    payload = {'type': 'TEST', 'raw_data':data}
    (rc, mid) = mqttc.publish("TEST", json.dumps(payload), qos=2)
    print 'i:{} rc:{} mid:{}'.format(i, rc, mid)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

PUB Client transferring to EMQ is good. But EMQ transferring to SUB Client is broken.

I change PUB Client's qos to 1. The messages are sent to the SUB client.

Why do not transfer to Sub client in qos 2?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `mqttc.loop()` function in the publishing code so the client can handle the multipart handshake required for QOS 2.

e.g.

```
for i in xrange(0, 100):
    print 'i:{}'.format(i)
    payload = {'type': 'TEST', 'raw_data':data}
    (rc, mid) = mqttc.publish("TEST", json.dumps(payload), qos=2)
    mqttc.loop()
    print 'i:{} rc:{} mid:{}'.format(i, rc, mid)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

You may want to look at some of the optional arguments for the loop function to control how long it will take to keep your timing right https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#network-loop